# Folium Heatmap HTML not displaying in browser

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to produce a heatmap with folium.plugins.HeatMap but when I save it as an HTML file, it doesn't display in the browser. In the browser console I'm greeted with the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZIndex' of undefined`. Here's my sample code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

hmap = folium.Map( location=[52.505,13.37], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=12)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(hmap)

points = [[52.505,13.37], [52.505,13.38], [52.505,13.39]]

folium.plugins.HeatMap(points).add_to(hmap)
hmap.save('heatmap.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to get the heatmap to display in the HTML is to edit the HTML file itself. In the code look for overlay definition, e.g.:

```
            var layer_control_8a341783a5d04238b1e40874f3876373 = {
                base_layers : {
                    "openstreetmap" : tile_layer_c92056f46452403fab918ce64ea24a7d,
                },
                overlays :  {
                    "macro_element_95af089726784f8d83b0878ea6f5c6de" : heat_map_95af089726784f8d83b0878ea6f5c6de,
                },
            };
```

And then delete everything that's within the overlays list, so in my example you'd be left with the following:

```
            var layer_control_8a341783a5d04238b1e40874f3876373 = {
                base_layers : {
                    "openstreetmap" : tile_layer_c92056f46452403fab918ce64ea24a7d,
                },
                overlays :  {
                },
            };
```

Save, refresh and the heatmap magically appears!